# What is the method for solving an equation in which a data set is compared with a "standard" with a known mean and variance?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, t-test, z-test

For my homework, I have been asked to solve the following question:

Suppose Wal-Mart had to pave over a valuable wetland to make room for a new Super-Store and associated parking lot. In obtaining the permit the city planners insisted that Wal-Mart create twice as much wetland in two other locations. One criteria for assessing the ‘ecological quality’ of the ‘created’ wetlands is to measure the population density of snails in particular habitats within the new wetlands. The ‘standard’, based on the previously existing wetland and several others is 30 snails per square meter (μ), with a variance (σ2) of 100. Wal-Mart invites you out to the two wetlands they have created and you do a snail survey of 30 1x1 meter quadrats in each wetland. Your data is below:

Wetland ‘A’: 42, 36, 40, 29, 45, 39, 28, 30, 32, 28, 39, 19, 21, 44, 27,
28, 51, 27, 34, 7, 61, 37, 31, 37, 33, 20, 33, 51, 23, 24

Wetland ‘B’: 0, 14, 9, 0, 27, 33, 6, 7, 10, 14, 8, 5, 2, 22, 12,
10, 18, 5, 30, 6, 18, 7, 8, 17, 17, 1, 28, 0, 4, 11

Does either of these wetlands meet the standard with 95% Confidence? Explain.

I have been trying for a few hours to hunt down in my textbook and online what the approach to solving this question is.  I am unsure on how to begin solving this question and what the answer would even look like.  I have access to Excel and JMP for working out basic statistics for each data set.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Does your textbook say anything about confidence intervals, z tests, or t tests?  Most likely it intends you to apply one of these.  Unfortunately, the question is worded too ambiguously to be definitely answered, because the standard is given as two values (a mean and a variance) and we are not told how to compare the wetland characteristics to those standards. In particular, what role is the variance standard supposed to play and is the confidence supposed to be a joint confidence or confidence in the two standards separately?

Comment: It does.  All of those topics are covered at length at various points throughout the text.  I can't, however, find an explanation for this specific type of problem.  It was created by my professor for an assignment, so its really not the textbook's fault.

I keep thinking that the mean is supposed to be the more important part of the problem.  But I'm really new to statistics, so I really don't know what I'm supposed to do with this.